# Getting Load average of CPU in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cpu-usage

I m trying to figure out getting load average of iOS system over time intervals of 1,5 and 15 minutes.
I have found the usage example regarding it which is as below :

```
double la[3];
getloadavg(la, 3);
NSLog(@"Load average : %f - %f - %f", la[0], la[1], la[2]);
```

What I don't understand here is the significance of 3.Should I pass 1, 5, 15 to getloadavg() function, or this is the correct method?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If it is like the version of this function on Linux, 3 is the number of samples to return, it is limited to at most three and you get the 1, 5, and 15 minutes numbers: https://linux.die.net/man/3/getloadavg

Comment: So the usage is correct i guess

Comment: I'd say yes, it's correct. This is verified by passing '2' and it returns averages for 1 and 5 minutes, but a -1 for 15 minutes.

Comment: Thanks @ norders

Answer (score 0):

I'd say yes, it's correct. This is verified by passing '2' and it returns averages for 1 and 5 minutes, but a -1 for 15 minutes.